# Create a class that can act as another

Tags: java, opencv, processing

I don't really have the vocabulary for the question I mean to ask. Here's my question: I'm using OpenCV (a library for Java/Processing). The code I have detects a face if there is one, then draws a rectangle around it, good starting point.

```
import gab.opencv.*;
import processing.video.*;
import java.awt.*;

Capture video;
OpenCV opencv;

void setup() {
  size(640, 480);
  video = new Capture(this, 640/2, 480/2);
  opencv = new OpenCV(this, 640/2, 480/2);
  opencv.loadCascade(OpenCV.CASCADE_FRONTALFACE);  

  video.start();
}

void draw() {
  scale(2);
  opencv.loadImage(video);

  image(video, 0, 0 );

  noFill();
  stroke(0, 255, 0);
  strokeWeight(3);
  Rectangle[] faces = opencv.detect();
  println(faces);

  for (int i = 0; i < faces.length; i++) {
    //println(faces[i].x + "," + faces[i].y);
    rect(faces[i].x, faces[i].y, faces[i].width, faces[i].height);
  }
}

void captureEvent(Capture c) {
  c.read();
}
```

My question is about the line Rectangle[] faces = opencv.detect();

Is it possible to create my own class that could be used in place of the Java Rectangle? I tried creating a class with the properties x,y,width,height, which is all it seems to have, but it said cannot convert from Rectangle[] to tracking.Trackbox[]

Basically I'd like to extend the functionality of the Rectangle class so that I can interpolate the x,y,w,h and make it smoother, among other things.

Comment: `java.awt.Rectangle` is not `final`. You could extend it or anonymize.

Comment: you can create a class that extends Rectangle and use it. For example,
class MyRectangle extends Rectange { ... }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no. You can't simply convert from one class to another like that. The opencv.detect() line returns an array of Rectangles, so that's what you have to use.

However, you might create a class that **extends** Rectangle. You'd then convert each Rectangle in the array to your extended  class, perhaps through a copy constructor:

```
class MyRectangle extends Rectangle{
   public MyRectangle(Rectangle r){
      super(r); //use the copy constructor in the Rectangle class
   }

   //then you could add your own methods
   public int getArea(){
      return getWidth() * getHeight();
   }
}
```

Then you'd need to convert the Rectangle array into a MyRectangle array, by iterating over the array and creating a new one using the copy constructor:

```
Rectangle[] faces = opencv.detect();
MyRectangle[] converted = new MyRectangle[faces.length];
for(int i = 0; i < faces.length; i++){
   converted[i] = new MyRectangle(faces[i]);
}
```

Note that this is just one way of doing this. You might also create a class that **contains** a Rectangle, and then uses that to perform custom actions. Something like this:

```
class MyRectangle{
   private Rectangle r;

   public MyRectangle(Rectangle r){
      this.r = r;
   }

   public int getArea(){
      return r.getWidth()*r.getHeight();
   }
}
```

Which approach you take depends on exactly how you want to organize your code, but those are the basics.

Comment: Thanks so much! Also great avatar B^) Now I'm wondering, why extend the class at all if I'd just have to convert it in the end? I could instead iterate and do like newClass[i].width = faces[i].width, etc. no?

Comment: @prismspecs You could do exactly that. The reason for extending is that you could then pass your class into any function that required an instance of Rectangle. It's really up to you.

Answer (score 0):

The point is that the left hand side of your assignment doesn't change "what happens on the right hand side": opencv.detect() is implemented as it is; returning an object of class Rectangle. And obviously, a "Rectangle" is not a "TrackBox"; and therefore you end up with this class cast exception.

The only way to change that would be to change the implementation of that method; but of course, that is rather impossible here; given the fact that you do not own that method.

What you could do instead: use the "wrapper" pattern; and create a class that holds a "Rectangle" object; but provides a "different" interface to the users of that wrapper class.